# How Can I Control The Space-Between Flex Boxes?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm experimenting with the css property flexbox to make fluid grids. I noticed that when I use `space-between`, that the spaces are not consistent. They start off wide then get narrower. How can I make the gutters equal to 1rem in flexbox?

I tried using `calc` to reduce with by 1rem. That only stopped the gutter from getting narrower than 1rem, but allows it to start off wider than 1rem.

Any other technique I can try?

My Code:

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.bg-blc-2 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.txt-ctr {
  text-align: center;
}
.cls-1,
.cls-2,
.cls-3,
.cls-4,
.cls-5,
.cls-6,
.cls-7,
.cls-8,
.cls-9,
.cls-10,
.cls-11,
.cls-12 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}
.cls-1 > * {
  flex: 1;
}
.cls-2 > * {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 1rem);
}
.cls-3 > * {
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 1rem);
}
.cls-4 > * {
  flex-basis: calc(25% - 1rem);
}
.cls-5 > * {
  flex-basis: calc(20% - 1rem);
}
.cls-6 > * {
  flex-basis: calc(16.6667% - 1rem);
}
.cls-7 > * {
  flex-basis: calc(14.28% - 1rem);
}
.cls-8 > * {
  flex-basis: calc(12.5% - 1rem);
}
.cls-9 > * {
  flex-basis: calc(11.11% - 1rem);
}
.cls-10 > * {
  flex-basis: calc(10% - 1rem);
}
.cls-11 > * {
  flex-basis: calc(9.09% - 1rem);
}
.cls-12 > * {
  flex-basis: calc(8.33% - 1rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="cls-1">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-2">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-3">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-4">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-5">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-6">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-7">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">7</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-8">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">7</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">8</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-9">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">7</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">8</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">9</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-10">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">7</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">8</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">9</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">10</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-11">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">7</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">8</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">9</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">10</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">11</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-12">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">7</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">8</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">9</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">10</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">11</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">12</div>
</div>
```

Here is the example problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xz4rbrgc/

Comment: it looks like a constant 16px between boxes, if you don't like the space on the left and right sides of .cls*, I think I can fix that too.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/68jIGZ1.png  http://i.imgur.com/Ff4Siaj.png

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Here's an alternate: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/x30boe1a/

This is a version with a flex column wrapped around the whole layout.

Using rem has it's merits but like flexbox, it still needs a little help from other properties because of certain requirements or circumstances.

This article covers a topic I believe is relevant to your project.

https://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/

**RELEVANT CSS**

```
html, body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.fcol-0 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: space-between;
    align-items: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
} 
div.bdr-lt {
    border-left: 0;
}
div.bdr-rt {
    border-right: 0;
}
div[class^="cls"] {
    border-top: 8px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 8px solid blue;
}
```

---

Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/fqeapejg/
I think you want a constant 1rem between the boxes right?

Using `box-sizing: border-box` will enforce a common box modal. Flexbox does not include borders even though `border-box` is applied. I didn't really know what purpose that was for until now. If borders were not ignored by flexbox, then you'd get no way of using a constant measurement within the flex container. I'm not sure why rem varies and acts like em. Rem should stay constant since the root's font-size is unchanged. That's why I used 8px for the borders, since you want a constant 1rem distance between boxes (1rem = :root font-size = 16px/2 (each box) = 8px.

Btw, I see that you declared 16px for body. If your intention was to set 1rem = 16px, then it should be `html { font-size: 16px; }`. I didn't bother because it's a default for all the browsers AFAIK.

Relevant changes:

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div[class^="bg"] {
    border-left: 8px solid red;
    border-right: 8px solid red;
}
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.bg-blc-2 {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.txt-ctr {
    text-align: center;
}
.cls-1, .cls-2, .cls-3, .cls-4, .cls-5, .cls-6, .cls-7, .cls-8, .cls-9, .cls-10, .cls-11, .cls-12 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0
}
div[class^="bg"] {
    border-left: 8px solid red;
    border-right: 8px solid red;
}

.cls-1 > * {
    flex: 1;
}
.cls-2 > * {
    flex: 0 1 calc(50%);
}
.cls-3 > * {
    flex: 0 1 calc(33.33%);
}
.cls-4 > * {
    flex: 0 1 calc(25%);
}
.cls-5 > * {
    flex: 0 1 calc(20%);
}
.cls-6 > * {
    flex: 0 1 calc(16.6667%);
}
.cls-7 > * {
    flex: 0 1 calc(14.28%);
}
.cls-8 > * {
    flex: 0 1 calc(12.5%);
}
.cls-9 > * {
    flex: 0 1 calc(11.11%);
}
.cls-10 > * {
    flex: 0 1 calc(10%);
}
.cls-11 > * {
    flex: 0 1 calc(9.09%);
}
.cls-12 > * {
    flex: 0 1 calc(8.33%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cls-1">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-2">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-3">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-4">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-5">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-6">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-7">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">7</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-8">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">7</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">8</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-9">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">7</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">8</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">9</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-10">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">7</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">8</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">9</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">10</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-11">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">7</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">8</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">9</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">10</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">11</div>
</div>
<div class="cls-12">
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">1</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">2</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">3</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">4</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">6</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">7</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">8</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">9</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">10</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">11</div>
  <div class="bg-blc-2 txt-ctr">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any difference other than you added a red border. 2 columns still have wider gutters than the 12 column row.

Comment: Also, when using short hand, calc will not work properly in other browsers that supposely support flexbox(coughs IE). Flex-basis must be used.

Comment: Sorry, didn't update properly. I guess you could substitute the shorthand as `flex-grow: 0`, `flex-shrink: 1` for each `.cls*`?

Comment: Even if I don't do shorthand, I see no difference.

Comment: Updated the borders to 8px; Each is spaced at 16px at different viewports.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I don't want borders, I want consistent gutters. The gaps between the flexboxes.

Comment: Want your doing can be done without borders and using 'justify-content: space-around'.

Comment: Also, REM is scalable if a user adjusts font via browser. So REM's must be used for spacing, not pixels.  I'm also aware of border-box and apply it to all elements as a reset, however didn't think it was necessary for this snippet because it doesn't apply or effect the problem we are trying to solve. I could nest elements to achieve desired effect, but I'm experimenting with this method to achieve that. In theory, the original script should work, I don't understand why the gutters are wider than 1rem.

Comment: In addition, REM gets the vale from the body, unless otherwise specified in the html. By default, html selector doesn't have a font value. I don't know of any browsers that set the font in html selector by default, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Ok, I see what you did. I switched to my tablet which isn't showing the code right. Using borders is a good idea, but can't have the first and last boxes have spacing/borders there. We could use the pseudo selectors to compensate for this, but then your over run with media queries. I'm not positive it would work well in a responsive fluid grid layout. My break points are at 40rem and every 20 REM after that(approximately every 320px).

Comment: @Xarcell I updated with a new version that looks and behaves very solidly.  Not only do I think it'll handle the media queries but it'll withstand a nuclear blast as well :P Give it a try I'm curious about the breakpoints as rem and how they hold up vs px.

Comment: I upvoted your work, but I cannot accept it because borders are used. If I were working on a personal project, I would probably use your method of transparent borders. This is part of a javascriptless framework I'm working on. What if someone want to put a legit border around their flexboxes? It would break spacing. It really is a good idea though. Also, align-items: space-between is invalid.

Comment: Using rem's for padding, margins, and breakpoints keep layouts relative to font size. I'm not suggesting using breakpoints to change font-size, what I mean is if a user with poor eyesight increases the font via browser settings, the enlarged font won't break the layout, because most measurements are based on root font size. If for example, your breakpoints are 640, 960, 1280 and a user with a 1280 viewport increases font via browser settings, the page would scale as if your were viewing 960 viewpoint, as opposed to the original 1280. Nothing gets squished or breaks out of alignment.

Comment: Indeed it's too rigid to be liquid and outline would be a poor substitute for borders. I cut and pasted most of the flexbox settings from a couple of my examples, I must've mixed it up with align-content. Browser font settings and IE never concerns me because my site has a font-size adjustment feature and my clients are required to use Chrome. Firefox, or Safari. Well I'll look in on this page occasionally and see if you get a solid solution , good luck @Xarcell